# Does modern sound cards typically contain an emulated OPL2 (YM3812) chip?

Tags: audio, hardware

*I did not know on which SE to put this question, since it is a bit about PC hardware and a bit about programming. If another SE site suits the question better, please go ahead and move it.*

Now to the actual question. In [this video](https://youtu.be/QLJSdNYcdpk?t=33), the narrator makes the following claim about the OPL2 / YM3812 sound chip:

> In fact, it is possible that the computer you're using right now still emulates that chip, either deep down in software or hardware, just like a modern video card still simulates old CGA/VGA graphics from the 1980 just for backwards compatibility.

My question is: **Is that claim true, or was it a pure invention?** I could not find any information on how to access this obscurely simulated OPL2 chip on a modern PC with my own program.

Of course it would be easy to pick up one of the many open source simulation of the chip, and simulate it in software, but that'd kill the point of accessing the simulated chip in modern sound card this guys mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice you cite is at best obsolete.

Audio interfaces (or adaptors) stopped being 'Sound cards' between 10 and 15 years ago.

The requirements for audio in the mean-time have changed dramatically: About 20 years ago, [PCM Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) was burdensome on PCs (although by no means unheard of), and putting a hardware synthesiser on the card (which was driven from MIDI, which the cards often had as well) was a reasonable compromise.

Over the intervening time, we've seen more and more system chipsets with on-board audio.  The video you cite is partially correct - in that we can use software synthesis to replace the functionality of the OPl2 hardware - although this is typically implemented by high-level operating system components.  Both Quicktime and WMP have MIDI software-synth units that can perform essentially the same functions - although neither is an emulation of the OPL2.

Finally, it's worth pointing out that the reason the OPL2 chipsets existed in the first places is that there was at one point a huge consumer market for them - in synthesizer keyboards.  The FM technology (which is, in any case, entirely digital) was a pragmatic and cheap way of implementing the required polyphony in the days when sample-subtractive methods (e.g. ROMpler) were too costly to implement in silicon.

Comment: So basically, the guy is wrong : OPL2 was emulated sometimes in more modern sound cards, but is not emulated anymore since the audio is embedded on the MB, is that correct ?

Comment: First, there are practically no modern 'sound cards'. Just integrated north-brdiges with audio interfaces. There isn't even emulation - just MIDI sequencer components with soft-synths at application level in multi-media stacks. Your source talks about paradigms of technology that simply don't exist any more.

Comment: Yes, sorry in my previous comment by "modern sound cards" I meant the late 90s ones, not the audio provided in today's PCs. The point is, the guy is wrong about OPL2 being simulated in modern computers, right ? (without explicitly written simulation software)

Comment: Yes. That particular FM synthesis model was the mother of invention: it was highly innovative in its time, but the market moved on to sample subtractive synthesis - not least because storage became ever cheaper for samples and, and FM was a bitch to program.